# Rust disable all tests for specific target

Tags: testing, rust, target-platform

I am working on a Rust crate and I would like to disable all tests for one specific target architecture (`wasm32`). I know you can disable specific source items using a `cfg` annotation:

```rust
#[cfg(not(target_arch="wasm32"))]
#[test]
fn only_compile_on_not_wasm32() {
    ...
}
```

But as I want to disable all tests, I would like a quicker way, preferably as a configuration in the `Cargo.toml` file. The crate looks like this:

```
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── ...
│   └── lib.rs
└── tests
    ├── ...
    └── mod.rs
```

i.e. the tests I want to disable are stored in the `tests` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have many test files, then you may disable entire modules applying it to the containing element:

```
#![cfg(not(target_arch="wasm32"))]
```